# What is the purpose of interkinetic nuclear migration during neurogenesis?

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, development, embryology

I am reading about [neurogenesis](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrm1739) and I am learning about the different types of neural stem and progenitor cells (neuroepithelial cells, radial glial cells and basal progenitors). I have read that these cells exhibit  interkinetic nuclear migration.

For example in neuroepithelial cells, the nucleus migrates to the basal side during G1 phase, is at the basal side during S phase, migrates back to the apical side during G2 phase, with mitosis occuring at the apical surface.

I am wondering if there is a clear purpose for interkinetic nuclear migration during neurogenesis? From some papers that I have read about the topic, it seems to me that the exact reason why this occurs in cells during neurogenesis is unknown, even though the molecules that are involved in the process have been identified.

Thanks.